# Where should my user interface code be located?

Tags: java, user-interface

Where should my user interface located in a simple CRUD application (with Java).
In my application I have the main class as well as another class which handles all the things which have something to do with the database e.g. getting information from it or adding new info to it.

Is it wiser to keep the UI-elements in the main class and leave the database class take the user input forward e.g. add a new element into database class, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(system.in);

   System.out.println("Give me your name:");
   String name = scan.nextLine();

   DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler();
   db.addNameToDatabase(name);  
}
```

Or should the input prompt exist inside the `DatabaseHandler`, so in the main-class only the method call is shown, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(); 
  db.addNameToDatabase(); //user interface now inside addNameToDatabase method  
}
```

Comment: [Please don't use the word 'question' in question titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114221/why-isnt-the-word-question-allowed-in-question-titles) (even if it's spelled wrong). We already know that this is a question. Try to find a good title that shows what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the size of your program. If your program is small and easy to read in one file then let it be so. As the program gets bigger then it becomes necessary for clarity to break it out. (If it is really small than a straight procedural way of coding might be the best within one class.)
In the case you break it out then the main class should be a driver for both the UI and data portions, which should be in different modules. You might want to look at different patterns like MVC or MVP on how to split it up.
As you can see there is no one way fits all. Large programs that are broken up into components/modules/packages are harder to get your arms around because of the wiring, but make it easier for a team to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Always during development, remember - [`high cohesion`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) and [`low coupling`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29). For your particular question, think this way - in either approach, are you having `high cohesion`? No. Why should the `database` class handle user input? And why the `main` method should handle user input? No, both your ways are,well ideally, wrong.

But we seldom come across ideal situations. Your IO should be handled by another class and your database should be handled by another class,so should your UI. And inside these classes as well, each method should have a specific task. Use getters and setters,for instance, in your IO class,to get and set variables. Each method doing what it should do  ensures high cohesion. And in this way, you end up ensuring low coupling as well,because your modules won't be interdependent. You might think - oh well, I can write all this in just one class and get it over with, but remember, this approach has a lot of advantage. In situations where the maintenance of your code has to be done by someone else, they would know by the names of classes and methods to know where to look for the issues. In situations where you have to look at your own code after ages, you wouldn't even recognize one word if you aren't organized in this manner.

Remember - high cohesion and low coupling FTW!

Ideally - your main should just be a starting point to your program, and nothing else.